# Can I use NoSQL database in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, nosql

I am trying to use a NoSQL database instead of a relational database such as MySQL in WordPress, but I am not sure if it is possible or not.

Any suggestion is very welcome.

Comment: please declare more about your objective (you may got vote down or force close for question that not consider as real question).

Comment: In my research i found NoSQL faster than RelationalDB, so i try to prove about this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wordpress only supports MySQL, so no, you cannot use a NoSQL DB. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Alternative_Databases

> Currently, the official WordPress distribution only supports the MySQL
>   database engine. A number of people have requested support for other
>   database engines, particularly the open-source PostgreSQL
> ... Current codebase is very MySQL-centric. While WordPress does use the ezSQL class to implement database calls, this cannot properly be called an abstraction layer.

Answer (score 7):

Somebody working on this already [here.](http://mongopress.org/)

Mongopress looks interesting.. Also found some wordpress devs also working on this... right now waiting for some of them to come up with a solution...

Comment: this project (Mongopress) seem to have died.